# Replacing all occurrences of words in a text file according to user input

Tags: python, text-files

Let's say I have a text file with the following:

```
dog
dog
cat
dog
bird
cat
```

I would ask the user what `dog`, `cat`, and `bird` should be replaced with. For example, `dog = red`, `cat = yellow`, and `bird = green`. My text file then is the following:

```
red
red
yellow
red
green
yellow
```

**How can I go about identifying unique words, and ask the user what to replace each unique word with?**

I know if I do:

```
content = open('tags.txt' 'r').readlines()
content_set = set(content)
```

I would remove duplicate entries.

**How about asking a user what to replace these words with? And then go on replacing these words?**

Here is my previous code, which opens a csv file and inserts contents into a text file:

```
import csv

csv_location = input("Location of CSV: ")
csv_location_get = csv_location.replace('\\','/')

with open(csv_location_get, 'r') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        # sku_row = row[0]
        category_row = row[6].split(';')
        category_split = category_row[0]

        with open('tags.txt', 'a') as txt_file:
            txt_file.write(category_split + '\n')

    content_old = open('tags.txt', 'r').readlines()

    content_new = set(content_old)

print(content_new)
```

Comment: Then what exactly is the question?

Comment: How can I go about identifying unique words, and ask the user what to replace each unique word with?

Comment: But you already know the first part of that, don't you? You've literally put it in the question! So have a go at figuring out the next step. Note that SO isn't a code-writing or tutorial service, you need a specific question; see [ask].

Comment: Yes, though would using sets be the correct way? But yes the main thing that confuses me is how I would replace the words, by asking the user what they should be.

Comment: Why do you think it's incorrect? Do you have tests? If so: does it pass them? If not: why not write some? You need to break down the problem into smaller steps, for example: do you know how to prompt the user for input? How to insert the word they're currently choosing a replacement for into the prompt? If not, go and research *that specific issue*. Again, **this isn't a tutorial service**, we aren't here to coach you through these basics.

Comment: search the API for `print()`  `input()`  `dict` (to store what new value you should replace what key with and `with open(filename, "w") as f: `. You then write the new file based on the readlines() or you open the old file per Read and Read/Write one line a time - whatever.

Comment: I understand how to do inputs and all that, this is just part of my code. My whole program asks a user for a CSV file's location, and puts contents of a specific column into a text file. This is where the finding/replacing comes in.

I originally made a web crawler that goes through product pages on a supplier's website, and extracts the data into the CSV. (The finding/replacing is to help me categorize these products, instead of going into each csv sheet and writing out the categories, I hope to find key words, and then insert the categories into the csv. I hope I explained this right.)

Comment: Then why haven't you tried using those same principles on this part of the code? What you've posted doesn't even try to use `content_old` as you describe.

Comment: Oh I just simplified it to show the concept as I didn't post the whole code in.

Comment: Search SO for `replace text in a file` - there may be a few answers out there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it very easily

First the text file that is be worked on has to be asked by the file in prompt or in command line so that and file can be opened and edited. -- like

open file (filename)
test1.txt (enter)

Then you can display the option available to the user -- like 
1) Change all the occurrence of the particular word / letter 
2) Save and exit
3) display file text (print the file)

based on uesr input -- (for your program input will be 1)

here you have 2 options 

First option

Prompt the user for entering the word to change its occurrence in the file with the another word.

Second option (most likely your choice)

display word by word unique 
like this

id      value     count

1-->   dog     (25 places)
2-->   cat    ( 2 places)

enter the number and the new word to change all the occurrence 
id new_Value

1 red

then you can change read the file for all the occurrence and change it with given word.

and then again prompt user with the option
 

1) Change all the occurrence of the particular word / letter 
2) Save and exit
3) display file text (print the file)

then user may view or he may save and exit 
you can do these things in copy or temporary text document of the original and when the user saves and exit make the changes to the original one

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

i do not know how to change the text file but you can create new one as you wish.
my solution is that : i would create two arraylist one contains all words with repetions if there is, and one contains all words without repetion. Liket that:
list1 : {dog, dog, cat, dog, bird, cat}
list2 : {dog, cat, bird}
Then i would print every word and ask for what user want to replace them with one by one. 
After that with one "for loop" and "if statement", i would change them